# Invalid hook call when dynamically importing components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've got this setup:

Component A that uses a hook

Component B that imports component A

When testing B I'm dynamically reimporting it with a `require(B)` on a `beforeEach` and resetting modules via `jest.resetModules()`
Doing the dynamic import to update other mocked values.

That seems to cause `Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call`. I'm not exactly sure why this happens. Did anyone run into this? What could be a fix here?

Here's a contrived example https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hodgkin-gz1tl, for some reason it runs fine in the sandbox but fails locally

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `Item` returning both state and function via `items`.

```
export function Item() {
  const items = React.useState([123, 234, 768]);
  return <div>Items - {items}</div>; <--- problem
}
```

From [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):

> It returns a pair of values: the current state and a function that updates it.

So it should be:

```
export function Item() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([123, 234, 768]);
  return <div>Items - {items}</div>;
}
```

or

```
return <div>Items - {items[0]}</div> <--- return state only
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad for not writing up the example better, I've updated to fix this. But that's not related to my testing issue